# nested range in Go template

Tags: html, templates, go, range

I have structure like these

```
type Users struct{  
    Name           string           `json:"Name,omitempty"`  
    Gender         string           `json:"Gender,omitempty"`  
    Communication  []*Communication `json:"Communication,omitempty"`  
}  

type Communication struct {  
    Type  string `json:"Type,omitempty"`  
    Value string `json:"Value,omitempty"`  
}
```

every user will have two communication structure like

```
[
    {
        "Type": "MOBILE",
        "Value": "12121212"
    },
    {
        "Type": "Email",
        "Value": "Some@email.com"
    }
]
```

In my template i want to display them in a table. iam getting the User structure values, but could not get the communication structure values

HTML Template file (partial code):

```
<tbody>  
{{range $key, $val := .Users}}   
<td style="text-align: center;">{{$val.Name}}</td>  
<td style="text-align: center;">{{$val.Gender}}</td>  
///////How to display communication values here??////////////  
{{end}}  
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Communication field just like other fields.

`{{$val.Communication}}`

Since you want each these entries in separate `<td>`s its easier if you could put them in a `map` instead of a `slice`. You could use a function like below for that.

```
sliceToMap := func(s []*Communication) map[string]string {
    comms := map[string]string{}

    for _, c := range s {
        comms[c.Type] = c.Value
    }

    return comms
}
```

You can register this as a custom function to be used in the template,

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "SliceToMap": sliceToMap,
}).Parse(src))
```

Then your template could be,

```
<tbody>  
{{range $key, $val := .Users}}   
<td style="text-align: center;">{{$val.Name}}</td>  
<td style="text-align: center;">{{$val.Gender}}</td> 

{{$comms := SliceToMap $val.Communication}}

<td style="text-align: center;">{{index $comms "mobile"}}</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">{{index $comms "email"}}</td>

{{end}}  
</tbody>
```

See these in [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/QHMRUI9XRi)

Comment: Thank you A H
how to check 
    if ($comm.Type == "Mobile")  
because i want to display it under the mobile column in my table

Comment: Will the first value always be "Mobile"? If you don't know the order maybe you could use a map instead of slice, if possible? Like `{"moblie": "12345", "email": "some@email.com"}`?

Comment: Thanks AH once again for a prompt reply.
Unfortunately i cannot change the structure format.  
some user will have email only, and some will have mobile only, and some both, so i need to check the Type
is there any way?

Comment: I can't figure out an easy way :( You could iterate over the list and find `mobile` and `email` values and pass them to the template. Maybe someone else has an answer. And I think you should edit the question to include your expected html output.

Comment: Hardy, I updated my answer. A lot. This is the best answer I could come up with.